# Check if a string of type char * contains another string

Tags: c++, string, pointers, parameters

I have a larger task of which contains this function. Here are the instructions;

> Define a C ++ function named isPartOf , with two parameter pointers to C strings
> (ie of type char * ,  not from the not yet detailed declared C ++ data
> type string ) and returns a Boolean value.
>
> In essence, the function should check whether the string pointed to it
> by the first parameter pointer, is part of the string pointed to it by the
> second parameter pointer.
>
> Examples: isPartOf ("heart", "hypertensive
> heart disease") returns true back isPartOf ("screw", "Case Involving
> wheelchair") returns false back.

I have been learning C for a year and have only begun learning C++ and I am finding it hard to understand the use of 'char *' and parameters in general. It took me awhile to understand pointers and now parameters have thrown me off. I have tried this code with probably all possible iterations of * and & just to see if it will work but it does not.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void isPartOf(char *, char *);

int main()
{
    char * Word;
    char * Sentence;

    cout << "Please enter a word: ";
    cin >> Word;
    cout << endl << "Please enter a sentence: ";
    cin >> Sentence;
    cout << endl;

    isPartOf(Word, Sentence);

    if (isPartOf(Word, Sentence))
    {
        cout << "It is part of it";
    }
    else
    {
       cout << "It is not part of it";
    }
}

void isPartOf(char a, char b)
{

}
```

My two main questions here are;

1. How do parameters work in this case?
2. Is there a function that will check if a string exists in a string? If not, how should I start going about coding a function of the sort?

Comment: Your declaration on top doesn't match the definition on th  bottom. The parameter ypes should be the same.

Comment: Simple solution: Loop through both strings. When you find characters in one string that match another, increase a count variable. If not, reset it to zero. At the end of the loop check if count is equal to the length of the other string.

Comment: Answer to #2 - in C, yes: strstr.  Have a look at the boyer-moore algorithm or http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_string_matching_algorithm.

Comment: Where do you allocate memory to hold your characters for the word and sentence when you input?  You've declared pointer, but haven't made them point to anything.  The `cin` function will input characters and place them at the location pointed to by the pointer `Word`.  And where is it pointing to before you input?

Answer (score 5):

Based on @alex.b code, I wrote the following lines. I also considered the fact that it was forbidden to use any library functions

```
bool isPartOf(char* w1, char* w2)
{
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    while(w1[i] != '\0')
    {
        if(w1[i] == w2[j])
        {
            int init = i;
            while (w1[i] == w2[j] && w2[j] != '\0')
            {
                j++;
                i++;
            }

            if(w2[j] == '\0')
            {
                return true;
            }
            j = 0;
        }

        i++;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: I really needed a function to be used in Windows Kernel Mode driver. Thank you for this!

Answer (score 4):

Since this is C++, the simplest solution would be to use `string`. You can't actually `cin` a character array the way you're trying to (that code doesn't do what you think it does), so that solves your input problem too:

```
std::string Word, Sentence;
cout << "Please enter a word: ";
std::getline(std::cin, Word);
cout << endl << "Please enter a sentence: ";
std::getline(std::cin, Sentence);
cout << endl;

if (isPartOf(Word, Sentence)) { 
    // ...
}
```

The other nice thing about `string` is that it makes `isPartOf()` very simple:

```
bool isPartOf(const std::string& word, const std::string& sentence) {
    return sentence.find(word)    // this returns the index of the first instance
                                  // word
           != std::string::npos;  // which will take this value if it's not found
}
```

Alternatively, it can be implemented using [`strstr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strstr):

```
    return strstr(sentence.c_str(), word.c_str());
```

Comment: That's the problem, I believe they don't want me to use string, which is why I am finding this so difficult.

Answer (score 1):

A char* is a pointer to the first memory address of the first character in a string. When you first declare a char* it is not set to a memory address so you won't be able to store any data in it. So you need to allocate memory to that char* so you can begin to store data in it. For example:

```
word = (char*) malloc(number_of_bits * sizeof(char));
```

Remember malloc requires you to include stdlib.h

```
#include <stdlib.h>
```

Once you have space to start storing data in that char* you can then use cin to read in data.

Also when you are passing a pointer to another function you need to make sure the parameter you are passing the char* to is also of type char*

```
void isPartOf(char *a, char *b){
    ...
}
```

And lastly to determine whether or not another string contains a substring I would use the strstr function

```
bool isPartOf(char *a, char *b){
   if(std::strstr(b,a) != NULL){    //Strstr says does b contain a
      return true;
   } 
   return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

bool isPartOf(char* w1, char* w2)
{
    int i=0;
    int j=0;

    for(i;i < strlen(w1); i++)
    {
        if(w1[i] == w2[j])
        {
            j++;
        }
    }

    if(strlen(w2) == j)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

int main()
{

    char wrd1[] = "As I know there is a function in C++ string which performs substring search: string1.find(string2)";
    char* W1 = wrd1;
    char wrd2[] = "search";
    char* W2 = wrd2;


    if(isPartOf(W1,W2))
        cout << "true";
    else
        cout << "false";

    return 0;
}
```